# sort this "Apr-19" "Apr-18" type of date in ascending in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, type-conversion, sql-order-by

sort in ascending order whole column having a date in this format

```
Apr-18 |
Apr-19 |
Dec-15 |
Feb-19 |
Nov-13 |
Nov-17 |
```

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(DateTime, Date,101)
```

this is not working

Comment: which db you are really using ??  and which data type is the column  with  your date ?

Comment: @scaisEdge db used is mysql and datatype is str

Comment: This date format is not complete to be sortable - you need a year. At any rate, you have to convert your string to DATE or DATETIME first.

Comment: ´Do not store Dates as string. Store Dates in a date type

Comment: "this is not working" is not a problem description. Always describe the problem precisely; do you get error's? What are the error messages? Is the output unexpected? then what output do you expect. Help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

The convert syntax you're using belongs to [[image]sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server), not [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql).

For MySQL, you can use [`str_to_date`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
ORDER BY SELECT str_to_date(DateTime, '%b-%y');
```

Comment: it is sorting month but the year is not getting sorted

Comment: ORDER BY SELECT str_to_date(DateTime, '%b-%y'); Worked

Comment: @IndianCricket oh, those are years! Sorry, I thought they were days. I edited my answer to fix the format string to treat these as years.

Answer (score 0):

im mysql should be 
if DateTime  is a valid datetime column

```
order by date_format(datetime, '%b-%d')
```

if DateTime  is a string  column  you should use str_to_date

```
order by str_to_date(datetime, '%b-%d')
```

Comment: @IndianCricket  answer  updated .. with proper format